# Dynamic Sorting with multiple Criteria field in Java

Tags: java, sorting, dynamic, criteria

I need to sort a list of Dynamic object with a list of dynamic search criteria. So  I have a method which accepts

```
sort(List<SortCriterion> sortCriteria, List<T> searchList){

}
```

Now If I have an object list of TradeOperator which looks like this. I can send other object Like CarOperator in the sort method.

```
 public class TradeOperator implements SearchResult{

      private String name;
      private String address;
      private String status;
      private Long   regNum;
      private Double price;
}
```

The SortCriterion code looks like this.

```
 public class SortCriterion{

       protected String field;   
       protected String direction;
    }
```

where the field could be TradeOperator.name and the direction = ASC or DESC. Now i can pass the list of  SortCriterion   with multiple fields and direction.

Here is what I did. I Collected all the fields which are ASC and all the field which are DESC in a MAP sortValues with Key = ASC and DESC and Values are list of the Field. Then Sort it in ASC and then in reverse order.

```
sort(List<SortCriterion> sortCriteria, List<T> searchList){
   Map<String, Set<String>> sortValues = new HashMap<>();
    populateSortedValues(sortCriteria, "ASC", sortValues);//group fields on ASC or DESC as key = ASC and Value = List of Fields
    populateSortedValues(sortCriteria, "DESC", sortValues);

    if (null != sortValues.get(Constants.ASC_ORDER))
    {
        for (String ascendingOrder : 
         sortValues.get(Constants.ASC_ORDER))
        {
        Collections.sort(list, new SearchResultComparator(ascendingOrder));
        }
    }

    if (null != sortValues.get(Constants.DESC_ORDER))
    {
        for (String descOrder : sortValues.get(Constants.DESC_ORDER))
        {
        Collections.sort(list, new 
               SearchResultComparator(descOrder).reversed());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the SearchResultComparator class.

```
public class SearchResultComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

private String getter;


public SearchResultComparator(String field) {
    this.getter = "get" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1);

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    try {
        if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {
            o1 = o1.getClass().getMethod(getter, new Class[0]).invoke(o1, new Object[0]);
            o2 = o2.getClass().getMethod(getter, new Class[0]).invoke(o2, new Object[0]);
            if(isDouble(o1.toString()) && isDouble(o2.toString())){
                Double d1 =  Double.parseDouble(o1.toString());
                Double d2 =  Double.parseDouble(o2.toString());
                return (d1 == null) ? -1 : ((d2 == null) ? 1 : ((Comparable<Double>) d1).compareTo(d2));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SystemException("Cannot compare " + o1 + " with " + o2 + " on " + getter, e);
    }

        return (o1 == null) ? -1 : ((o2 == null) ? 1 : ((Comparable<Object>) o1).compareTo(o2));


}

public boolean isDouble(String value)
{
try
{
    Double.parseDouble(value);
    return true;
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    return false;
}
}
```

}

Its Sorting in One way. if I sort a field in ASC then another field in DESC the ASC sort is getting lost. Please help. I am new to Java.

Comment: If you are indeed new to Java then you are probably in over your head.  As you present it, your task requires the use of reflection (which indeed you are using) and reflection is *not* a topic well suited for newbies.  That's not the only reason to start with something simpler, but it's enough.

Comment: At a glance it looks like you're trying to add more than one value for keys in your HashMap. Maps can't do this. Instead they simply discard the old value and take on the new value.

Comment: The ASC and DESC Map works fine, The Only problem is if we send multiple SortCriterion, with both ASC and DESC it takes the DESC sort and ASC sort is gone. I would have love to sort in DB, but we can't modify any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need SearchResultComparator or segregate ASC and DESC. Use this technique for chained sorting an any order.

```java
sort(List<SortCriterion> sortCriteria, List<T> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T one, T two) {
            CompareToBuilder compToBuild = new CompareToBuilder();
            sortCriteria.stream().forEachOrdered(sc -> {
                String fieldName = sc.getField();
                String direction = sc.getDirection();
                String fv1 = getFieldValue(fieldName, one);
                String fv2 = getFieldValue(fieldName, two);
                if(direction.equals("ASC")) {
                    compToBuild.append(fv1, fv2);
                }
                if(direction.equals("DESC")) {
                    compToBuild.append(fv2, fv1);
                }
            });
            return compToBuild.toComparison();
        }
    });
}
```

Get the field value using reflection

```java
private String getFieldValue(String fieldName, T object) {
    Field field;
    try {
        field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;// or ""
    }
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        return (String) field.get(object);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;// or ""
    }
}
```